# How can I enumerate/list all installed applications in Windows XP?

Tags: c++, python, winapi, enumeration

When I say "installed application", I basically mean any application visible in [Control Panel]->[Add/Remove Programs].

I would prefer to do it in Python, but C or C++ is also fine.

Comment: How do you define "installed application"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean the list of installed applications that is shown in Add\Remove Programs in the control panel, you can find it in the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

[more info about how the registry tree is structured can be found here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247501).

You need to use the [winreg API](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/winreg.html) in python to read the values from the registry.

Comment: THat key is empty on my system. Check the OS lsiting at the bottom of your link and you'll see it's not for WinXP.

Comment: @R.A, this registry key contains a lot of sub-keys (sub folders). Each represent a program in the uninstall list. Please read about the structure of that key in the mentioned link.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I find them in that regkey actually, my system froze for a while and I made a fast judegement since the link you gave didn't mention XP. Guess the article's just old.

Comment: It's used in both XP and Vista: http://www.vistax64.com/attachments/tutorials/7151d1223671005-programs-features-remove-uninstall-entry-32bit_reg.jpg

Comment: That knowledge base article lists older versions of the OS.  It might or might not work in newer versions.  Unless you can find it documented in the MSDN library, you probably shouldn't rely on it.  I'd look at WMI as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 10):

Check out the [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378(VS.85).aspx) WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) class. [Here's a tutorial](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi.html) on using WMI in Python.

Comment: I second this. Getting used to the WMI will help you with other windows admin related tasks. I recently wrote a sample for how to use the WMI from C++. 

http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/376

Comment: There are some caveats, though. WMI can be disabled on some PCs. Also, it does not list all the applications visible in the Control Panel applet -- only those installed by a compliant installer.

Answer (score 8):

Control Panel uses Win32 COM api, which is the official method (see Google Groups, Win32)
Never rely on registry.

Comment: Many years late, but -1 for not saying *which* COM API was used. A usenet group is big; saying "go Google it" in an answer is not good enough.

Comment: Control Panel uses COM API but I guess the API then reads from the registry. Which indirectly means that it rely on the registry.

Answer (score 7):

The Microsoft Script Repository has a script for listing all installed software.

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product")
for objItem in colItems:
    print "Caption: ", objItem.Caption
    print "Description: ", objItem.Description
    print "Identifying Number: ", objItem.IdentifyingNumber
    print "Install Date: ", objItem.InstallDate
    print "Install Date 2: ", objItem.InstallDate2
    print "Install Location: ", objItem.InstallLocation
    print "Install State: ", objItem.InstallState
    print "Name: ", objItem.Name
    print "Package Cache: ", objItem.PackageCache
    print "SKU Number: ", objItem.SKUNumber
    print "Vendor: ", objItem.Vendor
    print "Version: ", objItem.Version
```

Answer (score 6):

The best registry-based implementation that I have seen is the one written by Chris Wright (chris128) posted at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=598355. It uses multiple registry keys and is a lot more complex than any of the answers currently posted here. It seems to produce identical results to the Add/Remove Programs app, and like the ARP app it also provides an option to include updates.

Although it's implemented in VB.NET, it should be easy to convert to other .NET languages like C# or IronPython. I imagine that converting to IronPython first should make it fairly easy to port to regular Python if that's what you want, but I only converted it to C# myself and then cleaned up the code a bit.

Only one small bug to point out: GetUserInstallerKeyPrograms() doesn't add the version for user programs to the list, even though it extracts it. This is easy to fix though.

Answer (score 3):

C#.net code for getting the list of installed software using WMI in xp and win7(wmi is the only way in win7)

```
    WqlObjectQuery wqlQuery =
      new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlQuery);

        foreach (ManagementObject software in searcher.Get()) {
            Console.WriteLine(software["Caption"]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP mentioned XP and also mentioned Python, C or C++ but I found that a lot of information on the net about this topic is either incomplete or incorrect. An example of the latter is the suggestion to use WMI--specifically, the `Win32_Product` class; however, as is noted elsewhere, that method is *slow*, partly because, believe it or not, each MSI found actually runs its repair. I call that solution incorrect because of how painfully slow it is and because of its nasty side-effect. For instance, you have already opted to disable a program's Windows service but calling `select * from Win32_Product`, as part of ensuring that the MSI repair runs, will apparently re-enable the service.

For what it's worth, below is what I would consider to be the most complete example to date, albeit in C# (I compiled it against Framework 4.6.1 but lower versions may work too.) It lists 32-bit and 64-bit installed programs; it disposes registry keys that it uses and it runs in under a second, at least after caching kicks in. Improvements are welcome.

One thing it *is* still missing is some updates. For example, when I run it on my Windows 10 system and compare it with Control Panel | Programs and Features | Installed Updates, I notice that it does not show `Security Update for Adobe Flash Player` for some reason.

I don't have any good reason for the anonymous method, it's just how I was thinking at the time--a sort of method-within-a-method solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = InstalledProgram.GetAllInstalledPrograms();

        result.Sort((a, b) => a.DisplayName.CompareTo(b.DisplayName));

        foreach(var program in result)
        {
            if(!program.IsSystemComponent && !program.IsKB) Console.WriteLine(program.Dump());
        }
    }
}

public enum PlatformTypes
{
    x86,
    amd64
}

public class InstalledProgram
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    extern public static int RegQueryInfoKey(
        Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle hkey,
        StringBuilder lpClass,
        ref uint lpcbClass,
        IntPtr lpReserved,
        IntPtr lpcSubKeys,
        IntPtr lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
        IntPtr lpcbMaxClassLen,
        IntPtr lpcValues,
        IntPtr lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
        IntPtr lpcbMaxValueLen,
        IntPtr lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
        out long lpftLastWriteTime
    );

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public string UninstallString { get; private set; }
    public string KBNumber { get; private set; }
    public string DisplayIcon { get; private set; }
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    public DateTime InstallDate { get; private set; }
    public PlatformTypes Platform { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSystemComponent { get; private set; }
    public bool IsKB { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(KBNumber); } }

    public static List<InstalledProgram> GetAllInstalledPrograms()
    {
        var result = new List<InstalledProgram>();

        Action<PlatformTypes, RegistryKey, string> getRegKeysForRegPath = (platform, regBase, path) =>
        {
            using(var baseKey = regBase.OpenSubKey(path))
            {
                if(baseKey != null)
                {
                    string[] subKeyNames = baseKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                    foreach(string subkeyName in subKeyNames)
                    {
                        using(var subKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(subkeyName))
                        {
                            object o;

                            o = subKey.GetValue("DisplayName");
                            string displayName = o != null ? o.ToString() : "";
                            o = subKey.GetValue("UninstallString");
                            string uninstallString = o != null ? o.ToString() : "";
                            o = subKey.GetValue("KBNumber");
                            string kbNumber = o != null ? o.ToString() : "";
                            o = subKey.GetValue("DisplayIcon");
                            string displayIcon = o != null ? o.ToString() : "";
                            o = subKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                            string version = o != null ? o.ToString() : "";
                            o = subKey.GetValue("InstallDate");
                            DateTime installDate = o != null ? parseInstallDate(o.ToString()) : default(DateTime);
                            o = subKey.GetValue("SystemComponent");
                            bool isSystemComponent = o != null ? o.ToString() == "1" : false;

                            // Sometimes, you need to get the KB number another way.
                            if(kbNumber == "")
                            {
                                var match = Regex.Match(displayName, @".*?\((KB\d+?)\).*");
                                if(match.Success) kbNumber = match.Groups[1].ToString();
                            }

                            // Sometimes, the only way you can get install date is from the last write
                            // time on the registry key.
                            if(installDate == default(DateTime))
                            {
                                string keyFull = baseKey + "\\" + subkeyName + "\\DisplayVersion";
                                var sb = new StringBuilder(64);
                                uint sbLen = 65;

                                RegQueryInfoKey(
                                        subKey.Handle
                                        , sb
                                        , ref sbLen
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , IntPtr.Zero
                                        , out long lastWriteTime);

                                installDate = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastWriteTime);
                            }

                            if(displayName != "" && uninstallString != "")
                            {
                                result.Add(new InstalledProgram
                                {
                                    DisplayName = displayName,
                                    UninstallString = uninstallString,
                                    KBNumber = kbNumber,
                                    DisplayIcon = displayIcon,
                                    Version = version,
                                    InstallDate = installDate,
                                    Platform = platform,
                                    IsSystemComponent = isSystemComponent
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        getRegKeysForRegPath(PlatformTypes.amd64, Registry.LocalMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        getRegKeysForRegPath(PlatformTypes.amd64, Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        if(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            getRegKeysForRegPath(PlatformTypes.x86, Registry.LocalMachine, @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
            getRegKeysForRegPath(PlatformTypes.x86, Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string Dump()
    {
        return Platform + "\t" + DisplayName + "\t" + InstallDate + "\t" + DisplayIcon + "\t" + Version + "\t" + KBNumber + "\t" + UninstallString;
    }

    private static DateTime parseInstallDate(string installDateStr)
    {
        DateTime.TryParseExact(
                installDateStr
                , format: "yyyyMMdd"
                , provider: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
                , style: System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None
                , result: out DateTime result);

        return result;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DisplayName;
    }
}
```

[Sigh] and then I saw @PolyTekPatrick's answer. How did I miss that?