# How to list Add/Remove Programs on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

For Windows desktop, the Add/Remove Programs list exists in the registry (as described 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802499/how-can-i-enumerate-list-all-installed-applications-in-windows-xp)).  I would like to list the same programs in Windows Mobile (5+), but the registry entries don't seem to exist in that location.

Searching the registry did not yield any positive results.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://windowsmobilepro.blogspot.com/2006/03/programmatically-find-out-all-programs.html). For older platforms you look at the registry key:

```
\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Apps\Appname\
```

All installed applications should have the "InstallDir" and "Instl" keys there. The "Instl" must have a value of 1.

For newer platforms you need to use the [Configuration Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889539.aspx).