# Getting the list of softwares installed using Java on a computer

Tags: java

How can one get a list of installed software and its version in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There's [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860968/check-for-installed-program-on-windows-using-java) that checks for the existence of a particular software.

You can make a list of all filepaths that have

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

in the beginning, then take whatever is at the end of this filepath to be the name of the software.

Comment: but isn't it OS dependent as, i can only make it work with Windows. But what if i want it to work with Linux as well? Is it possible to parse the file location or search for the name of software in a particular directory? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: For Linux:

In order to run Linux shell commands from Java, see [example](http://linuxprogram.wordpress.com/2006/10/22/how-to-excute-a-linux-shell-command-in-java/)

As for what to run: [see this](http://linuxprogram.wordpress.com/2006/10/22/how-to-excute-a-linux-shell-command-in-java/)

Comment: i am extremely sorry but how would this post, solve my problem?

Comment: Alright. Going step by step.
You first write a program that runs the Linux shell command (which gives a list of software/apps installed in the Linux machine) for you, then save the result in a list. This list is what you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much @Antimony but which linux shell command gives the list of applications installed?

Comment: Dude. Read my second comment properly, it's got 2 links. You might have missed the second one.

Comment: But aren't they same? Both the link redirect to the same web page! Thank you mate!

Comment: @Spaniard89 For Linux distributions, [see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/how-do-i-list-all-installed-programs).

Answer (score 0):

I think following code might help you. I am new to java so pls edit my code if any changes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class getInstalledAppList {

  private static final String REGQUERY_UTIL = "reg query ";
  private static final String REGSTR_TOKEN = "REG_SZ";
  static String s = REGQUERY_UTIL + "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software"
                    + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";





public static String getCurrentUserPersonalFolderPath() {
    try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());

      reader.start();
      process.waitFor();
      reader.join();

      String result = reader.getResult();
      int p = result.indexOf(REGSTR_TOKEN);

      if (p == -1)
         return null;

      return result.substring(p + REGSTR_TOKEN.length()).trim();
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }



  static class StreamReader extends Thread {
    private final InputStream is;
    private final StringWriter sw;

    StreamReader(InputStream is) {
      this.is = is;
      sw = new StringWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        int c;
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
          sw.write(c);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      }

    String getResult() {
      return sw.toString();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {

      getDisplayNameDword( getCurrentUserPersonalFolderPath()  );
  }

  private static void getDisplayNameDword(String str){

      Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

      String [] array = new String[500];


      array = str.split("\n");

      for(String i : array){

          set.add( getName(i.trim()) ); 

      }


      Iterator i = set.iterator();

      while(i.hasNext()){

          System.out.println( i.next() );

      }

  }

  private static String getName(String s){
  Process process = null;
  try {
            // Run reg query, then read output with StreamReader (internal class)
             process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + 
                    '"'+ s + "\" /v " + "DisplayName");

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(process.getInputStream());
            reader.start();
            process.waitFor();
            reader.join();


            // Parse out the value
            String[] parsed = reader.getResult().split(REGSTR_TOKEN);
            if (parsed.length > 1) {
            return  (parsed[parsed.length-1]).trim();
            }

       } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
  return null;
  }
}
```

or use psinfo.exe to get installed app list in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little library ([JavaListApps](https://github.com/drone-ah/JavaListApps)) that does this based on [ListPrograms](https://github.com/mavenlin/ListPrograms) which is in turn based on a 
[VB Script](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?598355-Example-of-how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-programs-(like-Add-and-Remove-Programs))
linked from a 
[StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802499/how-can-i-enumerate-list-all-installed-applications-in-windows-xp/9757013#comment22371865_9757013)

My need is a little limited, so there are unimplemented parts compared to the C++ version.