# From where WMI getting the installed software list in windows? (either from registry or any other location)

Tags: c++, registry, wmi

I'm trying to get installed software list from my windows machine. I've found out WMI is the best way to get the same.I'm using a c++ application to get the details of installed application but I need to know from where WMI is getting all this details.

NOTE: Even if I changed the registries , it affect only in ADD/Remove programs(control panel) but my application getting the exact values. I have changed the registry values under **`"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`**

for my **`32-bit`** machine.

Could anyone, please let me know how it works?

Comment: Just iterate through the keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enumerate/list all installed applications in Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802499/how-can-i-enumerate-list-all-installed-applications-in-windows-xp)

Comment: Hi Asesh , Thanks for the quick response. I've  changed the registry values "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion‌​\Uninstall". this changes are affecting in Control panel also.
But my doubt is why WMI is not affecting accordingly. Is it getting deatils from registry or not , like Control panel.

Comment: @G.N.Raju No idea about WMI but add/remove programs will list by iterating through that registry key. Maybe Google can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of installed windows programs from WMI try
Win32_InstalledWin32Program

I don't know C++ but here's the cmd line

```
wmic path Win32_InstalledWin32Program get name
```